# What causes order or rows in table to change after a location.reload() function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I am battling with a somewhat trivial issue here. After a close a modal box it appears that the order of rows and even the pagination changes. Does anyone have any idea what causes this issue and how it can be prevented? Is there a way of avoiding the page reload after closing the modal ? Here is my code below

```
  $(function () {
                $(".anchorDetail").click(function () {
                    debugger;
                    var $buttonClicked = $(this);
                    var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
                    var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        //url: TeamDetailPostBackURL,
                        url:'/FilteredSearch/Client',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: { "Id": id },
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            debugger;
                            $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                            $('#myModal').modal(options);
                            $('#myModal').modal('show');


                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
                        }
                    });
                });


                $("#closebtn").click(function () {
                    $('#myModal').hide();
                    //e.preventDefault();
                    location.reload();
```

Comment: location.reload(); will reload the page and may result is changing the data/sort/page location.

Answer (score 1):

location.reload() is causing this behavior. You are able to get the modal to close without calling location.reload() in your closebtn click method.

Please try removing location.reload().